Java reflection - Get highest class to declare a method
I'm trying to get the "highest" class/interface that declares a method in java 8
Example:
package pkg;

public class Classes {

    public static interface IInterface {
        void iMethod();
    }

    public abstract static class AClass implements IInterface {
        protected abstract void aMethod();
    }

    public static class SubClass extends AClass {
        
        @Override
        public void iMethod() {
            System.out.println("Sub iMethod");
        }

        @Override
        protected void aMethod() {
            System.out.println("Sub aMethod");
        }
    }
}
// getFirstDeclarator(Classes.SubClass.class, iMethod) -> AClass
// getFirstDeclarator(Classes.SubClass.class, aMethod) -> IInterface

Here's what I tried to do, it works perfectly as long as the method is public (because Class#getMethod only works for accessible methods), except that it should also work for private/protected methods
import pkg.Classes;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Method iMethod = Classes.SubClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("iMethod");
        Method aMethod = Classes.SubClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("aMethod");
        System.out.println(getFirstDeclarator(Classes.SubClass.class, iMethod));
        System.out.println(getFirstDeclarator(Classes.SubClass.class, aMethod));

    }

    /**
     * Get the declaring class or interface of a method.
     * If the method is overridden, this method will return the highest superclass or interface that declares it.
     */
    public static Class<?> getFirstDeclarator(Class<?> startClass, Method method) {

        Class<?> superClass = startClass.getSuperclass();
        if (superClass != null) {
            try {

                // The problem is here: Class#getMethod only works for accessible methods
                superClass.getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());

                return getFirstDeclarator(superClass, method);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // The method is not declared in the superclass
            }
        }

        for (Class<?> iface : startClass.getInterfaces()) {
            try {
                iface.getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes()); // Same problem here
                return getFirstDeclarator(iface, method);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // The method is not declared in the interface
            }
        }

        return startClass;
    }
}

Do you know if there's a way to make this work for non-accessible methods? Or is there another way?

private methods in different classes are unrelated, even if they happen to have the same name and type. That doesn’t change if one class happens to be the superclass of another. Considering one of the methods to be the “first” contradicts the fact that they are unrelated.

Yes, use .getDeclaredMethods() instead.
There are 2 relevant things:

You want ALL methods, not just public/protected marked ones. getDeclaredMethods() does this. getMethods() does not.
You want the entire hierarchy - not just methods declared directly in the class whose j.l.Class object you are invoking a getMethods() on, but also its parentage. getMethods() does this. getDeclaredMethods() does not.

You can fix em both with a while loop. You keep looping, updating the j.l.Class instance you check with c = c.getSuperclass() until c is null (or, if you prefer, c == Object.class to avoid looping for Object which you are probably not interested in).
That class for which you no longer witness the method you are interested in? Whatever class you had in the previous loop is the right answer. Update a variable containing 'the answer' until the method is gone, then, return that answer.
Note that for interfaces, the entire concept of what you want does not exist. There is no such thing as 'first declarator'. Trivially:
interface Gun {
  void shoot(Person p);
}

interface Camera {
  void shoot(Person p);
}

class ReallyBadIdea implements Camera, Gun {
  @Override public void shoot(Person p) {
    System.out.println("Psychopathic news reporter?");
  }
}

What's the right answer when I call getFirstDeclarator(ReallyBadIdea.class, ReallyBadIdea.class.getMethod("shoot", Person.class))?
Unless your answer is 'an exception is thrown', you are wrong.
both Camera and Gun have a plausible claim to be the first declarator. Picking 'the first one declared' is incorrect because java goes out of its way to decree that ordering of implements interfaces does not matter; if you now introduce that all of a sudden it does, that's nasty. Architecturally that's a capital mistake. At best you can decree 'an arbitrary one' but unless you literally involve java.util.Random you're still introducing order relevance.
You may wish to revisit what made you think that you need this. It smells of an X/Y problem. You have some unknown problem (it is not clear from your question). You thought of a solution: "I know! I'll just get the first declarator, that will help!" .... "Oh, wait, this is more difficult than I thought, let me ask Stack Overflow about this.".
But, really, the problem is that your approach is probably wrong, because 'first declarator' should not matter, and is in fact unanswerable, even, for interfaces. 'first declarator' limiting yourself solely to classes could, possibly, be acceptable design. But 'first declarator' when interfaces are involved? I am having a very hard time imagining any problem where that is (part of) an appropriate solution.

I don't understand how you can use getDeclaredMethods instead of getMethods. Simply replacing it would break everything, since it doesn't check higher classes.
We can assume that the case where 2 different interfaces have a method in common never happens (so "an error is thrown" may be the answer).
I need to know the "first" class to remove redundancy from mappings (come to think of it, my approach of having the program do it itself is a bit convoluted).

I explained how you get both: You write a while loop, and call getDeclaredMethods on every class in the hierarchy. You have to read the whole answer.
